# Request physical cameras on CameraCharacteristics for Camera2 API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-13

I am looking to get the list of physical cameras on my device using Android SDK 31 target on a  SDK33 required device... but the returned camera id by
manager.getCameraIdList() doesnt have a list of compatible devices I am using CameraView library if that's relevant. I am looking for alternative solutions to find the logical and physical cameras

```
  protected final boolean collectCameraInfo(@NonNull Facing facing) {
        int internalFacing = mMapper.mapFacing(facing);
        String[] cameraIds = null;
        try {
            cameraIds = mManager.getCameraIdList();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            // This should never happen, I don't see how it could crash here.
            // However, let's launch an unrecoverable exception.
            throw createCameraException(e);
        }
        LOG.i("collectCameraInfo", "Facing:", facing,
                "Internal:", internalFacing,
                "Cameras:", cameraIds.length);
        //Context ctx =getCallback().getContext();
        for (String cameraId : cameraIds) {
            try {

                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                if(!CamerasDataInfo.containsKey(cameraId))
                {
                    String cameraName = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING).toString();
                    CameraDataInfo camInfo =new CameraDataInfo();
                    camInfo.CameraId = cameraId;
                    camInfo.CameraName ="";
                    CamerasDataInfo.put(cameraId,camInfo);
                }
                int[] capabilities = Arrays.stream(characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES)).toArray();
                Boolean containsMultipleCameras  = Arrays.stream(capabilities).anyMatch( x-> x ==CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA);
                if(containsMultipleCameras)
                {
                    Object[] physicalCamerasIds = characteristics.getPhysicalCameraIds().toArray();
                    for(Object physicalCamera :physicalCamerasIds){
                        String physicalId =physicalCamera.toString();
                        if(!CamerasDataInfo.containsKey(cameraId)){
                            CameraDataInfo physicalDataInfo = new CameraDataInfo();
                            physicalDataInfo.CameraId = physicalId;
                            CamerasDataInfo.put(physicalId,physicalDataInfo);
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (internalFacing == readCharacteristic(characteristics,
                        CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING, -99)) {
                    mCameraId = cameraId;
                    int sensorOffset = readCharacteristic(characteristics,
                            CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION, 0);
                    getAngles().setSensorOffset(facing, sensorOffset);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (CameraAccessException ignore) {
                // This specific camera has been disconnected.
                // Keep searching in other camerIds.
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```